# Tikz arrows and circles not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I'm using this website to draw graphs: http://madebyevan.com/fsm/

My graph is supposed to look like this:

[image: NFA]

The website creates the suitable LaTeX code which I put in my document:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
\draw [black] (18.04,-17.02) circle (3);
\draw (18.04,-17.02) node {$q_1$};
\draw [black] (8.7,-15.7) -- (15.07,-16.6);
\fill [black] (15.07,-16.6) -- (14.35,-15.99) -- (14.21,-16.98);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

But rather when I compile my document, it only shows the node's text, without the circle or arrow:

[image: compiled]

- I did use the following in the document's preamble:

  \usepackage{tikz}
- I write my documents in LyX.
- The code above works for my peers who tried it. (works = outputs the expected graph)

Thanks in advance!

-Alon

Comment: Drawing it manually is _much_ easier.

Comment: That's subjective... The website forementioned has a great interface for drawing these specific type of graphs.

Comment: It is only an automatic system. What do you expect from that except approximated coordinates and approximated paths? No automatic systems can do as well as human in this stuff. They even draw the arrow by filling a triangle - my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: How do you compile your file? Is there any way to tell LyX to use pdflatex (or xelatex or lualatex) and not just latex?

Comment: I use pdflatex...

Comment: @AlonEmanuel, JouleV has a point. I have the desired output as well when compiling with xe- lua- and pdflatex... Did your peers, whom successfully compiled the code, used LyX as well? What's the difference from their LyX to yours? Surely a reinstallation would do no harm.

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Yeah, they did in fact use LyX.
Thanks people! I guess I'll resort to reinstalling (which is isn't a pleasant experience, since I have to install a bunch of language packages lol)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer does *not* help to answer the question. It is meant to be a too-long comment.]

---

I can get the desired output with your code. Therefore there might be a problem with your LyX or your Ti*k*Z.

However, why do you have to go to external websites? when your code can be as simple as this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] (a) {$q_1$}; % A node bounded by a circle of diameter 1cm
\draw[Triangle-] (a)--++(-2,.4); % Draw an arrow to the node
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought `minimum size` for a circle meant its radius.

Comment: @subhamsoni But in fact it is the diameter. You can write a simple code to check.

Comment: If my tikz (or LyX) is infact faulty, do I have option of fixing it rather than reinstalling the entire program?

Comment: @AlonEmanuel I don't know, because it is very strange that you can have the node label but _not_ the paths.